# error: extraneous '}' at top level in swift http post and get request

Tags: swift, http, get, request

I am using an online swift playground to test  http post and get request, the post aspect works fine, but when i add the get request,it gives the following error"error: extraneous '}' at top level.

The post code works fine.

// Post method

```
var url = URL(string: "http://196.46.20.80:8085/fideldesign")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString  = "email=oshinowo_sola@yahoo.ca&amount=15000&description=swift&currency=566&fee=0&returnurl=http://www.oleronesoftwares.com&secretkey=2BC80A5EB5BB6A64A772F9806A7E9A0B16702043AB475DC4" // which is your parameters
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

//Getting response for POST Method
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return // check for fundamental networking error
        }

        // Getting values from JSON Response
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        do {
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? NSDictionary
        }catch _ {
            print ("OOps not good JSON formatted response")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The code is to post dynamic records from user input like email address,amount,description into an external url and then return the get request in json format.

Comment: There must be some missing/extra } in your code file.

Comment: Add the get method also.

Comment: Don't embed the URSession call in `DispatchQueue.main.asyn`. Instead use this for the response you get from URLSession request.

Comment: check `responseString`, I believe you will find that the format of the JSON is wrong (for example, it may start with a `}`)

Comment: hello **Sola Oshinowo** i tried this code in playground , working fine for me. no error i found (}) . if any other issue related response  pleas explain more about your question.

Comment: Thanks, after trying it on another playground,it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the project and opening it again.

I was getting this same error and also when I tried pressing Enter (typing newline character) on the line that was problematic (It was the last line in the file for me), Xcode would insert the characters

```
ker;")
```

into my editor.

I was getting this error, until I closed and reopened the project, in which these errors went away and the random characters stopped appearing also.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was replacing the file.

1. Create new file, **different name** than current buggy file.
2. Copy/paste code into this new file.
3. Go ahead and delete that file with the error.

..For some reason using the same name transferred over the error, even if I deleted the other file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).